# Using Python requests cannot access a private website while it works by using a browser

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to download some (.csv) files from a private website with Python requests method.

I can access the website by using a browser. After typing in the url, it pops up a window to fill in username and password.
After that, it starts to download a (.csv) file.

However, it failed when I used Python requests method.
Here is my code.

```
import requests

# username and pwd in base64
b64_IDpass = '******'
tics_headers = {
                "Host": 'http://tics-sign.com',
                "Authorization": 'Basic {}'.format(b64_IDpass)
               }
# company internet proxy
proxy = {'http': '*****'}
# url
url_get = 'http://tics-sign.com/getlist'

r = requests.get(url_get,
                 headers=tics_headers,
                 proxies=proxy)

print(r)
# <Response [404]>
```

I've checked the headers in a browser, there is no problem.
But why it returns `<Response [404]>` when using Python?

Comment: So could you provide a user for us to test?

Comment: You might be missing out on a csrf_token

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Sorry. But, when you don't log in, you can checked the status code in a browser, `401 Unauthorized`.

Comment: @BenjaminPhilip Thank you. Let me learn what's that.

Comment: Have you tried to use cookie to download it without login?

Comment: @guttentag_liu you can refer [this](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf) for info on csrf tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *post* your password and username before you get the link.

So you could try this:

```py
request.post("http://tics-sign.com", tics_headers)
```

And ***then*** get the info:

```py
request.get(url_get, proxies=proxy)
```

This has worked for me in all the previous sites have scraped which need authentication.
The problem is that each site has a different way for accepting authentication. So it may
not even work.

It also may be that python is not getting redirected to http://tics-sign.com/displaypanel/login.aspx. `curl` didn't for me.

---

**Edit**:

I looked at the HTML source of your website and I came up with this:

```py
login_data = {"logName": your_id, "pwd": your_password}

request.post(http://tics-sign.com/displaypanel/login.aspx, login_data)

r = request.get(url_get, proxies=proxy)
```

You can look at my [blog](https://benjamin-philip.github.io/2020-09-16-requests-with-python/) for more info.

Comment: It didn't work. If I post to `request.post("http://tics-sign.com/displaypanel/login.aspx")`, also `<Response [404]>`.

Comment: Hmph I don't know. Maybe I missed something out. Since this is a private site, I can't test much either. I suggest that you keep an eye out for `input` tags. Since I can't read the language, I also don't know if those checkboxes were important. You can curl the site and search for all occurrences of input with grep - if you use unix